# Python Script randomly failing - What tools can I use to determine the cause?

Tags: python, trace, watchdog, raspberry-pi3

I have a python script that I wrote as part of my pool automation project. I have made many changes to it over time improving it and adding functionally. As a result, I have not had the opportunity to allow it to run for long periods of time until recently when I (pretty much) got it where I wanted it. Now that I have let it run all the time, it is randomly failing and restarting (via watchdog support).

I am running this script on a Raspberry Pi3 via systemd and it includes watchdog support since I want/need it to run all of the time. The watchdog is catching the script when it fails and restarting it just like it is suppose to, but I would rather figure out what is causing the script to fail in the first place.

The script connects to a mysql database, grabs some information on the level of the swimming pool and how many watts are in use by my pool pump and then determines if we need to fill the pool. If we do, we use a relay to open a sprinkler valve attached to the pool, if not we do not do anything. We also check to see if the sprinklers are running, the pool pump is running and if someone has thrown the physical disconnect switch. It has a number of status LEDs that we use and a couple of switches along with a LCD screen talking via serial to the Pi.

This script is pretty much the only thing running on the Pi other than sshd and system stuff...no apache, no node-red, ftp, etc...

I have an ssh session open to the Pi and this session never fails, even when the script fails. A continuous ping to the pi shows zero packet loss, even when the script fails. My syslog shows the following when the script fails and is restarted:

```
Jun  6 08:08:56 scruffy systemd[1]: Unit pool_control.service entered failed state.
Jun  6 08:08:57 scruffy systemd[1]: pool_control.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Jun  6 08:08:57 scruffy systemd[1]: Stopping Installing Python script for Pool Fill Control /w watchdog...
Jun  6 08:08:57 scruffy systemd[1]: Starting Installing Python script for Pool Fill Control /w watchdog...
Jun  6 08:08:58 scruffy systemd[1]: Started Installing Python script for Pool Fill Control /w watchdog.
Jun  6 08:08:58 scruffy kernel: [34864.219647] gpiomem-bcm2835 3f200000.gpiomem: gpiomem device opened.
```

dmesg shows this when the script fails and is restarted:

```
[    8.938912] gpiomem-bcm2835 3f200000.gpiomem: gpiomem device opened.
[34864.219647] gpiomem-bcm2835 3f200000.gpiomem: gpiomem device opened.
```

The log for my program shows nothing out of the ordinary:

```
2016-06-06 13:26:24,387 INFO Notify socket = /run/systemd/notify
2016-06-06 13:26:24,616 DEBUG PushBullet Notification Sent - Pool fill control started successfully
2016-06-06 13:26:24,617 INFO pool_fill_control.py V2.6 (2016-06-05) started
2016-06-06 13:26:25,182 DEBUG Sprinklers are not running (RACHIO).
2016-06-06 13:26:25,183 DEBUG SPRINKLER_RUN_LED should be OFF. This is a BLUE LED
2016-06-06 13:26:25,184 DEBUG Watchdog Ping Sent
2016-06-06 13:26:25,611 DEBUG get_pool_level returned 1
2016-06-06 13:26:25,764 DEBUG pool_pump_running_watts returned 12 watts in use by pump.
2016-06-06 13:26:25,765 DEBUG PUMP_RUN_LED should be OFF. This is the YELLOW LED
2016-06-06 13:26:25,766 DEBUG POOL_FILLING_LED should be OFF. This is a BLUE LED
2016-06-06 13:26:25,766 DEBUG Pool Level OK (PFC_LEVEL_OK) sent to MightyHat
```

While the script is running, here is the output of top:

```
top - 13:29:36 up 15:01,  3 users,  load average: 0.05, 0.07, 0.05
Tasks: 119 total,   1 running, 118 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.7 us,  1.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:    947760 total,   390032 used,   557728 free,   114444 buffers
KiB Swap:   102396 total,        0 used,   102396 free.    97648 cached Mem
```

and meminfo:

```
root scruffy: log #  cat /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:         947760 kB
MemFree:          558160 kB
MemAvailable:     864020 kB
Buffers:          114460 kB
Cached:            97640 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           202888 kB
Inactive:          31192 kB
Active(anon):      23672 kB
Inactive(anon):     6140 kB
Active(file):     179216 kB
Inactive(file):    25052 kB
Unevictable:        1744 kB
Mlocked:            1744 kB
SwapTotal:        102396 kB
SwapFree:         102396 kB
Dirty:                16 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:         23844 kB
Mapped:            19188 kB
Shmem:              6424 kB
Slab:             140780 kB
SReclaimable:     132312 kB
SUnreclaim:         8468 kB
KernelStack:        1000 kB
PageTables:          668 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      576276 kB
Committed_AS:      92620 kB
VmallocTotal:    1114112 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
CmaTotal:           8192 kB
CmaFree:            3736 kB
```

Here is some more system information:

```
root scruffy: log #  uptime
13:41:58 up 15:14,  3 users,  load average: 0.02, 0.04, 0.05

root scruffy: log #  uname -a
Linux scruffy 4.4.9-v7+ #884 SMP Fri May 6 17:28:59 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Here is the systemd startup/shutdown script:

```
# This script starts and stops our pool fill control python script

[Unit]
Description=Installing Python script for Pool Fill Control /w watchdog
Requires=basic.target
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=notify
WatchdogSec=70s
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /root/pool_control/pool_fill_control.py
ExecStop=/root/pool_control/setupgpio.sh
Restart=always

# The number of times the service is restarted within a time period can be set
# If that condition is met, the RPi can be rebooted
#
StartLimitBurst=4
StartLimitInterval=180s
# actions can be none|reboot|reboot-force|reboot-immidiate
StartLimitAction=none

# The following are defined the /etc/systemd/system.conf file and are
# global for all services
#
#DefaultTimeoutStartSec=90s
#DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s
#
# They can also be set on a per process here:
# if they are not defined here, they fall back to the system.conf values
TimeoutStartSec=2s
TimeoutStopSec=2s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have tried running it on a fresh install of jessie as well as moving it to another Pi, all with the same results, after some indeterminate amount of time, the script fails and the watchdog restarts it.

The script in question is quite long, so I am not sure the proper procedure for posting it here, but I do have it on github here:

https://github.com/rjsears/Pool_Fill_Control/blob/master/pool_fill_control.py

I am looking for guidance on how to troubleshoot the code to determine what may be causing it to fail, or if I have some egregious code that jumps right out at someone with more experience with python. I do not have that much experience and this is my first (what I consider real) python script.

Eventually I want to interface this with an internal website to duplicate the physical functions (button presses, LEDs) via a webpage, but I want the script to work correctly before going much further.

And help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Still having the same issue, hoping someone can point me in the right direction!

Comment: Ouch! Really...? No one here is a python guru that can help point me in the right direction to see why this script fails at random times...?